# Can I return different ViewHolder class instance for each view holder type?

Tags: android

Following is my code:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    if (getItemViewType(i) == REMMEND_TYPE) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(viewGroup.getContext());
        recyclerView.setId(R.id.recycler_view);
        return new RecommendedViewHolder(recyclerView);
    } else {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.home_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new HomeViewHolder(view);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 5) {
        return REMMEND_TYPE;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
    // return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```

and I will got class cast exception:
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.adapter.HomeViewHolder cannot be cast to com.viewholder.RecommendedViewHolder

So I wonder to know is that I only can return one ViewHolder class type for one Adapter?

Comment: You can return different view holders, but why are you instantiating a recycler view inside the viewholder class?

Comment: you should put more adapter's code here.

Comment: why are you using RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(viewGroup.getContext());
        recyclerView.setId(R.id.recycler_view); instead of a viewholder layout which is to be returned

Comment: pls add the full stacktrace and the onBind method

Comment: I am using using RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(viewGroup.getContext()); recyclerView.setId(R.id.recycler_view) , no special reason , just because I think the layout only contains a recyclerview which is too simple.

Comment: The issue is I should not try to get the viewType by getItemViewType(i)  at onCreateViewHolder, because the i variable is veiwType by itself. I glad you guys reply me. I am happy to see the comments. from your names you guys should be English local speakers. I am from Chinese guys.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I got the class cast issue is that the second parameter 'i' in onBindViewHolder is viewType, not a position or index meaning, I am using the i in a wrong way, I should use the i as a viewtype directly. and I wonder know why I auto generate the override method the parameter is abbreviated to 'i', for me 'i' meaning index or position. I correct the code as bellow and it's ok now.

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == REMMEND_TYPE) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView(viewGroup.getContext());
        recyclerView.setId(R.id.recycler_view);
        return new RecommendedViewHolder(recyclerView);
    } else {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.home_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new HomeViewHolder(view);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 5) {
        return REMMEND_TYPE;
    }
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```